# synchronize scrollbar in Qt

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have 2 graphicsview each with a separate scrollbar, as seen in the [image](http://www.qtcentre.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=8192&d=1346939235). I wonder how I can synchronize, so that the move one the other moves too.

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304293/synchronize-scrollbar-in-qt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is quite simple, just connect each view's scroll bar's `valueChanged(int)` signal (or `sliderMoved(int)`) signal to the other view's scroll bar's `setValue(int)` slot, like so:

```
connect(view1->horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), view2->horizontalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int)));
connect(view2->horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), view1->horizontalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int)));
```